# insert collection data and fk into table oracle apex

Tags: oracle, collections, foreign-keys, oracle-apex

So the basic question is:
how can I retrieve the primary key from another table into other table as foreign key and at the same time insert stored input from the collections into the table?

With this process I can get the primary key from the table and insert it as foreign key in the other table:

```
DECLARE
  l_id table1.id%TYPE;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table1(val) VALUES ('Europe')
    RETURNING id INTO l_id;
  INSERT INTO table2(continent_id, val) VALUES (l_id,'Belgium');
END;
/
```

With this process however I can insert the stored information from the collection into the corresponding tables.

```
begin
for i IN (SELECT c001 AS a,c002 AS b, c003 AS c, c004 AS d
          from APEX_COLLECTIONS
  WHERE COLLECTION_NAME='ITEM_DATA'
  ORDER BY 1)
 loop
    insert into table1 (USERID,TEST1,TEST2, TEST3)
    values ( i.a,i.b,i.c,i.d);
  end loop;
apex_collection.delete_collection(p_collection_name=>'ITEM_DATA');
end;
```

However, I would like to develop a process in which both the foreign key and the stored information from the collections are entered into the tables at the same time.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1(FKID,USERID,PROGRAMID,COURSEID) VALUES (ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, (select c001,c002,c003 from APEX_COLLECTIONS WHERE COLLECTION_NAME='SAVED_DATA'))
```

Unfortunately I cannot insert a select statement in an insert into values statement.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood correctly, is this what you want?

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (FKID,USERID,PROGRAMID,COURSEID) 
 SELECT ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, c001, c002, c003 
 FROM APEX_COLLECTIONS 
 WHERE COLLECTION_NAME='SAVED_DATA';
```

Comment: the problem is, there are two tables. So when the form gets submitted, the stored data from collection will be inserted into tbl1. Then the ID will be generated. At the same when the form gets submitted, I want the stored data from other collection be inserted into tbl2 (this works) but as well I want to insert the Foreign Key from tbl1  (which is the generated ID from tbl1).